# How can I send request to the server with JSON data and fileupload from AngularJS client using $resource via JAX-RS(Jersey)?

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey, jax-rs, angularjs-resource

I want to send a request the request to the server with JSON data and an Image file in a single request via JAX-Rs. Using AngularJS $resource.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible. You can upload an image to the server with AJAX, if you target the very latest browsers by using `XmlHttpRequest2`, but you still won't be able to upload both image data and `JSON` in one request.  Generally this is handled by uploading a file inside an `iframe` and then triggering something in your angular app once the upload is complete.

If you google "angular file upload" there are numerous libraries that can help with this.